# How to list all the information in TagGroup

Tags: dm-script

I have a TagGroup file (gtg file) with multi-layers. For example:

```
top_layer:mid_layer1,true
top_layer:mid_layer2,'abc'
top_layer:mid_layer3,123
```

For dm-script, I think maybe I can list all the information by the combination of TagGroupCountTags(), TagGroupGetTagLabel(), TagGroupGetTagTypeLength(), TagGroupGetTagType(), TagGroupGetTagAsTagGroup().

But for the python API of dm-script, the command about TagGroup is much less. Is that possible to list all the information by using python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GMS 3.6.0 (latest released version) tagGroups map to Python dictionaries and can be used as such, which should make it easy to use. However, I'm personally not a Python expert and don't have example code at hand. :c)

(Earlier versions of GMS handle TagGroups in Python differently.)